# Jquery Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression, Can I detect and skip it?

Tags: jquery

I am looking at data in two list. The first list has bad data and throws Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression.

How can I check for this bad data and continue with my code execution? Another option maybe log the error and continue?

Is there some way to detect a error in general or would I have to check the data for each character?

Two html lists.

```
//$("#listOne > li").first(); has the bad data in the data-info attribute.

<ul id="listOne">
   <li data-info="a/[%ref%*]" data-infoTwo="x">One</li>
   <li data-info="b" data-infoTwo="y">Two</li>
   <li data-info="c" data-infoTwo="z">Three</li>
</ul>

<ul id="listTwo">
   <li data-info="a">One</li>
   <li data-info="b">Two</li>
   <li data-info="d">Four</li>
</ul>
```

Jquery

```
$('#listOne li').each(function () {
   $("#listTwo li[data-info=" + $(this).data("info") + "]").data("infoTwo", $(this).data("infoTwo"));              
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd solve that by simply quoting the attribute value

```
$("#listTwo li[data-info='" + $(this).data("info") + "']").data("infoTwo", $(this).data("infoTwo")); 
//                       ^                            ^
```

Comment: Can some characters escape that?

Comment: If they were in the data.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but `$('[data-info=a/[%ref%*]]')` ends up being invalid because of the special characters, while if you quote it, as in `$('[data-info="a/[%ref%*]"]')` it's okay.